# Do more generalizations of Schur's inequality exist?

Tags: reference-request, inequalities

> I meet this following problem
>   If $$n\ge 3,\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\prod_{j\neq i}(a_{i}-a_{j})\right)\ge 0$$
>   where $a_{i}$ are real numbers.

when $n=3$, it is [Schur's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality)
 so which $n$ such this inequality?

but for  more generalization  form of Schur'.s Inequality exists?

Comment: For $n=4$ choose $a_{1}=10$, $a_{2}=9$, $a_{3}=7$, and $a_{4}=2$ for a counter example for your version of Schur's inequality. However, if one allows for further constraints one can prove something similar to Schur's inequality, see e.g. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212017315001152. (Actually I got my example from that paper.) For $n$ even you can choose numbers with the smallest number far below the others to construct a very large negative term.

Comment: this inequality hold only for $n=3,5$,see my answer:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346798/do-more-generalizations-of-schurs-inequality-exist